# Replacing a word with another word zero or more times in javascript using regular expressions

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I have a word : `[lesserthen]` , that I need to replace with `<` zero or more times in a string. I'm using the `String.replace` method to do so. But the word is only replaced one time in the string, I need to be replaced more then one time. I'm very weak with regular expressions and I'm interested to find a solution for this problem.

Here is the code I've been using:

```
var wordReplaced="This a text with one [lesserthen], and another [lesserthen]";
wordReplaced=wordReplaced.replace("[lesserthen]","<"):
```

The result I am aiming is:

> This a text with one <, and another <

But what I got instead is:

> This a text with one <, and another [lesserthen]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using an actual regex (with "g" option) in the replace instead of a search string, for example:

```
wordReplaced = wordReplaced.replace(/\[lesserthen\]/g,"<");
```